# Become a fan of a Facebook page through the API?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-page

I'm writing an iPhone application. I've seen widgets you can place on your website that users can click on to become a fan of your page. However, looking through the API or documentation, I can't find a way that you can facilitate "becoming a fan" through an application. I've spent about a day and a half pouring through the Facebook API docs and the cloud.

Has anyone else had success with this?

For example, say I was writing an app that listed cars, and I wanted to become a fan of the Delorean from within my app -- is there a way to do this?

If there is no solution, the alternative way I can think of is using a webview and linking to a page with a fan widget.

Comment: I should note, the webview method doesn't seem to work... using the iFrame method of displaying the widget shows up in a webview, but because the action of clicking the button opens a popup window, it won't work in a webview.  You'd have to forward the user out of your app into safari on the iphone (which may work -- haven't tested that).  -- Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fan'ing via the API is currently not possible.

Most probably, the reason for this is it would be to hard to avoid developers tricking users into become fans.

The only way is the [Fan Box plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/). It's possible to remove all elements via CSS to leave just the button.

Most Apps either use the button or simply link to the page.

Comment: Thanks, this is kinda what I've been finding out too... have you had success using the fan widget through a webview, or do you have to kick the user into Safari?